# Opening OLE files in C# 2012 or above, OLE files were created in Delphi 7

Tags: c#, delphi, com, ole

I am trying to open tmp file created within Delphi 7. I have been told they are OLE files which can contain anything from a Word doc to an image. 
The files are named like tmpdoc.tmp To open the said file within Delphi 7:
  using OleCtnrs;

OleContainer : TOleContainer;

```
        OleContainer.LoadFromFile(sTmpDocFolder+TMP_DOC_FILENAME);

        try

        sOleStr := OleContainer.OleClassName;

         bWord := (Pos('WORD.DOC',Uppercase(sOleStr)) > 0) or
        (Right(Uppercase(sOleStr),4)='.DOT') or
        (Right(Uppercase(sOleStr),4)='.DOC') or
        (Right(Uppercase(sOleStr),5)='.DOCX'); // Word 2007

        if bWord then begin
          if (Right(Uppercase(sOleStr),5)='.DOCX') or ( Pos('Word.Document.12', sOleStr)>0) then sExportFilePath := sExportFilePath + '.docx'
          else sExportFilePath := sExportFilePath + '.doc';
          OleContainer.DoVerb(ovOpen);
          OleContainer.OleObject.application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(sExportFilePath);
          SysUtils.DeleteFile(sTmpDocFolder+TMP_DOC_FILENAME);
         end;
           Result := True;
           SysUtils.DeleteFile(sTmpDocFolder+TMP_DOC_FILENAME);
       except
       end;
```

I think the Key is within OLECtnrs.pas and replicating LoadFromFile and LoadfromStream in C#.

```
procedure TOleContainer.LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
var
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TOleContainer.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  DataHandle: HGlobal;
  Buffer: Pointer;
  Header: TStreamHeader;
begin
  DestroyObject;
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Header, SizeOf(Header));
  if (Header.Signature <> StreamSignature) and not FOldStreamFormat then
    raise EOleError.CreateRes(@SInvalidStreamFormat);
  DataHandle := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, Header.DataSize);
  if DataHandle = 0 then OutOfMemoryError;
  try
    Buffer := GlobalLock(DataHandle);
    try
      Stream.Read(Buffer^, Header.DataSize);
     finally
      GlobalUnlock(DataHandle);
    end;
    OleCheck(CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(DataHandle, True, FLockBytes));
    DataHandle := 0;
    OleCheck(StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes(FLockBytes, nil, STGM_READWRITE or
      STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, nil, 0, FStorage));
    OleCheck(OleLoad(FStorage, IOleObject, Self, FOleObject));
    FDrawAspect := Header.DrawAspect;
    InitObject;
    UpdateView;
  except
    if DataHandle <> 0 then GlobalFree(DataHandle);
    DestroyObject;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

I have researched this for a while. I eventually found OpenMcdf 2.0. I thought this would open the files. However, I have had no joy as I think the headers are different.

Please help kind people of Stackoverflow. Any ideas or pointer would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The old .DOC fileformat is an OLE file but the new .DOCX format has nothing to do with OLE. OpenMcdf will work with old .DOC and .DOT files but not with .DOCX files. The new .DOCX file is actually a zip file containing the data of your Word-document.